# IE 11 Responsive layout not fully responsive on smaller sizes

Tags: internet-explorer, responsive-design

I have a block of code that contains a header and 3 images. When I resize the component on Chrome or Firefox it resizes to mobile perfectly but when I test on IE all versions it gets to around 610px and then stops shrinking fluidly to match the screen width. Instead it creates a scrollbar at the bottom. Has anyone had this problem before?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
   <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="st_ImagePanels">
          <div class="fd_ImagePanels">
             <div class="gp_ImagePanels">
                <div class="in gradient-bg">
                   <div id="welcomeMsg">
                      <h1 id="welcome">Welcome, Optical!</h1>
                   </div>
                   <div id="imageWrapper">
                      <div class="cp_ImagePanel">
                         <div class="in">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/465x260" alt="Image 1" />
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="cp_ImagePanel">
                         <div class="in">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/465x260" alt="Image 2" />
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="cp_ImagePanel lastElement">
                         <div class="in">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/465x260" alt="Image 3" />
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>


/* !== Global Rules */
/* !== Global Settings */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

/* !== Mixins */
/* !== Components */
html {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100%; }

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: url("../images/bg.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; }
  @media (min-width: 1600px) {
    body {
      font-size: 140%; } }
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    body {
      font-size: 110%; } }
  @media (max-width: 620px) {
    body {
      font-size: 80%; } }

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; }

[class*=st_] {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; }

[class*=fd_] {
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 73.125em;
  margin: 0 auto; }

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

h1 {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  display: block; }

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.625em;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase; }

.cp_LoginPanel {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto; }
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    .cp_LoginPanel {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0 3%; } }
  .cp_LoginPanel .in {
    border: 1px solid #c1c8cb;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 1; }
  .cp_LoginPanel #topPanel {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    background: #2f99cb;
    padding: 1.25em 0.625em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1.875em; }
  .cp_LoginPanel img {
    width: 1.875em;
    height: auto; }

#login-form {
  padding: 0 1.875em 1.875em 1.875em; }
  #login-form .inputBlock {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 1.25em;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center; }
    @media (max-width: 620px) {
      #login-form .inputBlock {
        display: block; } }
  #login-form label {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #666; }
    @media (max-width: 620px) {
      #login-form label {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 0.3125em;
        display: block; } }
    #login-form label#error {
      font-size: 0.875em;
      color: #ff0000;
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 1.875em;
      display: none; }
  #login-form input {
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0.3125em 0.625em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 1em;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    box-sizing: border-box; }
    @media (max-width: 620px) {
      #login-form input {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0; } }
    #login-form input:focus {
      border: 1px solid #2f99cb;
      box-shadow: none;
      outline: none; }
  #login-form input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #2f99cb;
    color: #fff;
    float: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 0.9375em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
            transition: all 0.2s linear; }
    #login-form input[type="submit"]:hover {
      background: none;
      color: #2f99cb;
      border-color: #ccc; }

.st_ImagePanels {
  padding: 3.125em 0; }

.gp_ImagePanels {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto; }
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    .gp_ImagePanels {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0 5%; } }
  .gp_ImagePanels > .in {
    border: 1px solid #c1c8cb;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden; }

#welcomeMsg {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  background: #2f99cb;
  padding: 1.25em 0.625em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1.875em; }
  #welcomeMsg h1#welcome {
    margin: 0;
    }

#imageWrapper {
  padding: 0 1.875em 1.875em 1.875em;
  overflow: hidden; }

.cp_ImagePanel {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5%; }
  @media (max-width: 620px) {
    .cp_ImagePanel {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center; } }
  .cp_ImagePanel:last-of-type {
    margin: 0; }
    @media (max-width: 620px) {
      .cp_ImagePanel:last-of-type img {
        margin-bottom: 0; } }
  .cp_ImagePanel img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto; }
    @media (max-width: 620px) {
      .cp_ImagePanel img {
        margin-bottom: 1.25em; } }

.gradient-bg {
  background: #ffffff;
  /* Old browsers */
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%, #f1f1f1 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #ffffff 0%, #f1f1f1 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffffff 0%, #f1f1f1 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f1f1f1',GradientType=1 );
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */ }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sssfd615/

Comment: You are showing the coloring book but not the crayons. We need the CSS posted, also.

Comment: I posted a fiddle. The CSS is rather long but I will post that too :)

Comment: Are you simply resizing the browser, or using the mobile emulator?  Mobile IE doesn't always behave the same as the desktop version.

Comment: Just simple resizing the browser.